# Vuex commit commits only the last value of an array from a response

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, vue.js, vuex

I am working on a Laravel vue.js project with vuex but am having an issue committing a response to the store. I can successfully fetch the array data  from the back end, but when I commit the response the store only the last value of the array is mapped to state, resulting in incorrect results upon iteration. But when I manage the state locally within the component it works correctly. Here is a sample response in my console window:

```
[{…}]
0: {id: 4, auth_id: 3, user_id: 3, power_id: 3, created_at: "2019-01-19 
12:49:15", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
app.js:90087 

(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, auth_id: 2, user_id: 2, power_id: 1, created_at: "2019-01-19 
12:03:52", …}
1: {id: 5, auth_id: 3, user_id: 2, power_id: 1, created_at: "2019-01-19 
12:50:02", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
app.js:90087 

[{…}]
0: {id: 2, auth_id: 2, user_id: 2, power_id: 2, created_at: "2019-01-19 
12:06:55", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
app.js:90087 

(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 3, auth_id: 3, user_id: 3, power_id: 2, created_at: "2019-01-19 
12:46:48", …}
1: {id: 6, auth_id: 3, user_id: 3, power_id: 2, created_at: "2019-01-19 
12:50:22", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Here is how I am fetching it and making a commit:

```
fetchVotes() {
  axios.get('/api/superpowers/fetchVotes/' + this.powerId + '/'
      this.userId)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.$store.commit('fetchVotes', response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => { console.log(error) });
},
```

then in the store mutation but only the last value of the array is mapped to state votes:

```
fetchVotes(state, payload) {
  state.votes = payload
},
```

but when I manage the state locally as below it works:

```
 fetchVotes() {
   axios.get('/api/superpowers/fetchVotes/' + this.powerId + '/' +
       this.userId)
     .then(response => {
       console.log(response.data);
       this.votes = response.data
     })
     .catch(error => { console.log(error) })
 },
```

Note that the `fetchVotes` method is called within forEach loop. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how do you know that commit is mapping only the last item?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim am triggering results in my vue template and also from the vue  dev tools. But its not really the last item. Every time I get a different value from the last one.

Answer (score 0):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Vuex is a plugin of Vue, so reactivity of Vuex's state follows same rules as reactive property in Vue. In your case, since the property you update is an array of objects, Vue only detect changes in size of array, not details of each item in array. So if you need to trigger updates in view layer, you have to use `Vue.set` instead:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

...

fetchVotes(state, payload) {
  Vue.set(state, 'votes', payload)
},
```

and if you need to delete items from your array, use `Vue.delete` instead of `delete`.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. the votes state in vue devTools is now zero using the above but let me have look on the above link may I can have a way around.